# I can't upgrade windows because the new operating system is not compatible with one device. What should I do?

Tags: windows-10

My mom says that his office doesn't work well.

So, I decided to uninstall office. Turns out office 365 that used to work well, fail to work because I need .net framework.

So I download .net framework and I was told that I need to upgrade windows to anniversary edition.

Well, I tried to update but windows say that I am up to date.

So I tried to force update using windows creation tool.

And I got this

[image]

Basically, one device, that I don't even use, prevents me from upgrading my surface pro 2

And I can't remove it because it's one with my surface pro.

Is there a way?

Also why doesn't realtek card reader compatible with my surface pro?

It's not a USB device by the way. It's built in in the surface

I checked the web and see that the problem is exactly this

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/realtek-stopping-my-surface-pro-3-from-updating/bc715f5a-6934-4b8b-8a73-82d47f581327

Comment: It is likely to be a USB device, connected internally to the main board USB ports.

Comment: "Turns out office 365 that used to work well, fail to work because I need .net framework." - Office does not require .NET, even if it does, .NET is built into all supported versions of Windows.  **I am not aware of any Surface Pro model that has a built-in USB 3.0 card reader.** We really need more information.

Comment: I am holding off submitting an answer until this question has more information.  For instance, I would want to see the output (formatted) of SetupDiag.  This will help diagnose the reason the feature upgrade is failing (even though we already know it's a device incompatibility). After the question is in a state it can be answered I can provide an answer. I basically have an answer ready to go.

Comment: Without understanding what version of Windows 10 you are currently on, it's difficult, to suggest solutions to your problem. Understand the reason Windows Update has failed to install a feature update, and allow your system to run an unsupported build, is also important information

Comment: Other people have the same problem. I will points out

Comment: What is your Surface Pro model? The device description says "USB" - have you connected it externally?

Comment: @user4951 - Instead if submitting a comment saying other people have the same problem, you should be providing the information, that is required to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Quick googling shows you're not the the only one to bump into this... MS Support pages themselves have multiple articles about this. According to [MSPoweruser](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-releases-updated-driver-surface-pro-3-devices-running-windows-10-anniversary-update/) Microsoft has released an update, but most of the pages I saw talk about Surface Pro 3. You could download firmwares and drivers from [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49042](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/surface-pro-2-update-history-9da532d8-2072-b6e1-7865-57fb7b3fffd9)

Here's Microsoft's (apparently) complete Surface Pro 2 update history. The latest listed release is from August 2021, so at least they haven't abandoned the platform yet :-)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/surface-pro-2-update-history-9da532d8-2072-b6e1-7865-57fb7b3fffd9

Realtek site also might have a driver / firmware update that'd help.

If their available offerings don't help I don't see many other options but talking to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

- Download the new Windows ISO
- Use Device Manager to disable the Realtek USB 3.0 Card Reader
- Reboot the Surface
- Use Device Manager to delete the Realtek USB 3.0 Card Reader
  (do not reboot to avoid automatic reinstall after the reboot)
- Install the Windows 10 Update from ISO
- Reboot the Surface.

Comment: I did that. It doesn't really work. It's fixed though

Answer (score 0):

I followed instruction here

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/realtek-stopping-my-surface-pro-3-from-updating/bc715f5a-6934-4b8b-8a73-82d47f581327

I forget which one is actually working. I remember updating the drive and not disabling or deleting it.

After that I forget whether I install from media creation tool or from update assistant.

For some reason it works.

The problem is a chicken and egg problems.

Basically you can't update windows because the driver is incompatible. You can't update driver because you don't have updated windows.

So I take a gamble and update the driver first thinking it will fail because the windows is not compatibel.

It sort of works.